# Multiple tabs on the same page issue

Tags: jquery, html

```js
$(function() {

  $('.tabs .tabsNav a').click(function(e) {
    $('.tabs .tabsNav a.current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');

    $('.tabs div.linkTab:not(:hidden)').hide();
    $(this.hash).show();

    e.preventDefault();
  });


});
```

```css
ul.tabsNav li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}
ul.tabsNav li a {
  background-color: #898989;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
ul.tabsNav li a.current {
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  color: #000;
}
.tabs div[class="linkTab"] {
  background-color: #FFF;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 6px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
.tabs div.selected {
  display: block;
  background-color: #FFF;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 6px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
  <ul class="tabsNav">
    <li><a href="#link1" class="current">Tab1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#link2">Tab2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#link3">Tab3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div id="link1" class="selected linkTab">
    tab1
  </div>
  <div id="link2" class="linkTab">
    tab2
  </div>
  <div id="link3" class="linkTab">
    tab3
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tabs">
  <ul class="tabsNav">
    <li><a href="#link1" class="current">Tab1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#link2">Tab2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#link3">Tab3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div id="link1" class="selected linkTab">
    tab1
  </div>
  <div id="link2" class="linkTab">
    tab2
  </div>
  <div id="link3" class="linkTab">
    tab3
  </div>
</div>
```

Hi! I have this code

If there is one set of tabs it work great, but if are two (like in my fiddle), when I click one of button my JS change the same div(first).

I want to make each set to be independent.

Thanks

Comment: Can't say this enough, but UNIQUE ID'S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to target elements within the same `.tabs` element as the clicked header, also ID of an element must be unique in a page.

```js
$(function() {

  $('.tabs .tabsNav a').click(function(e) {
    var $tabs = $(this).closest('.tabs');
    $tabs.find('.tabsNav a.current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');

    $tabs.find('div.linkTab:not(:hidden)').hide();
    $(this.hash).show();

    e.preventDefault();
  });


});
```

```css
ul.tabsNav li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}
ul.tabsNav li a {
  background-color: #898989;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
ul.tabsNav li a.current {
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  color: #000;
}
.tabs div[class="linkTab"] {
  background-color: #FFF;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 6px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
.tabs div.selected {
  display: block;
  background-color: #FFF;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 6px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
  <ul class="tabsNav">
    <li><a href="#link1" class="current">Tab1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#link2">Tab2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#link3">Tab3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div id="link1" class="selected linkTab">
    tab1
  </div>
  <div id="link2" class="linkTab">
    tab2
  </div>
  <div id="link3" class="linkTab">
    tab3
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tabs">
  <ul class="tabsNav">
    <li><a href="#link101" class="current">Tab1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#link102">Tab2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#link103">Tab3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div id="link101" class="selected linkTab">
    tab1
  </div>
  <div id="link102" class="linkTab">
    tab2
  </div>
  <div id="link103" class="linkTab">
    tab3
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are removing the `current` class of each and every `tabsNav`. Instead, remove for `tabsNav` from only current `tabs`.
Just change

```
$('.tabs .tabsNav a.current').removeClass('current');
```

to

```
$(this).parents('.tabs').find('a.current').removeClass('current');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the different ids for the next `ul`. You have given same ids.

```
<ul class="tabsNav">
    <li><a href="#link4" class="current">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#link5">Tab2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#link6">Tab3</a></li>
</ul>           
<div id="link4" class="selected linkTab">
    tab1
</div>
<div id="link5" class="linkTab">
    tab2
</div>
<div id="link6" class="linkTab">
    tab3
</div>
```

**Note:** Ids should be unique.